# Javascript Filter array has element on click/ multiple option

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, filter

I try to write an filter in Javascript, which sorts different content blocks with headlines (the headlines are the filters). 
I´ll try to explain what kind of filter I want to have.
For example I´ve 3 contentenblocks the first is only content1 the secont is content 1,2 and 3 and the third is content 2 and 3.
I wrote sth. like that.

HTML:

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center">                              
                                        <div id="filter1" class="filter_btn">
                                            Filter 1
                                        </div>                                       
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center">                           
                                        <div id="filter2" class="filter_btn">
                                            Filter 2
                                        </div>                                      
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center">                                     
                                        <div id="filter3" class="filter_btn">
                                            Filter 3
                                        </div>                                       
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center ">                                        
                                        <div class="filter_check">
                                            filter checker
                                        </div>                                        
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-center ">                                 
                                        <div class="filter_clear">
                                            filter clear
                                        </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           <div class="container">


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none filter1 filter1_only">
                                        <a href="">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                                                    <h4>filter1 only content</h4>


                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none  filter1 filter2 filter3">
                                        <a href="">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                                                    <h4>filter1 and filter2 and filter 3</h4>

                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                                         <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none   filter2 filter3">
                                        <a href="">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                                                    <h4>filter2 and filter 3</h4>

                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

JS sth like that

```
    var array = new Array();

$(function () {

    $('.filter_btn').click(function () {
        array.push(this.id);

    });

    $('.filter_clear').click(function () {
       $(".post").hide();
        array = [];


    });

    $('.filter_check').click(function () {
        alert(array);

    });


});




$(function () {
    $('#filter1').click(function () {


            $(".filter2:not(.filter1_only .filter1)").hide();
            $(".filter3:not(.filter1_only .filter1)").hide();
            $(".filter1").show();

                               });
    });

//
$(function () {
    $('#filter2').click(function () {

            // $(".filter1_only:not(.filter2_only .filter2)").hide();
            // $(".filter3_only:not(.filter2_only .filter2)").hide();

            $(".filter2").show();

    });
});
$(function () {
    $('#filter3').click(function () {

            // $(".filter1_only:not(.filter3_only .filter3)").hide();
            // $(".filter2_only:not(.filter3_only .filter3)").hide();

            $(".filter3").show();

    });
});
```

I tried to do sth with arrays und array. IndexOf but  I do not know how to go on with this...

[DEMO Code-Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBXRym?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var fil1 = "";
var fil2 = "";
var filcomp = "";




$(function func() {



/*Filter 1*/
$("#Filter_btn_1").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option1";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_2").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option2";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_3").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option3";
    filter();
});

/*Filter 2*/
$("#Filter_btn_4").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option4";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_5").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option5";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_6").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option6";
    filter();
});



filcomp = fil1 + fil2;



$('.filter_btn').click(function () {


    $(".filter_btn").removeClass("filter_selected");
    $(this).addClass("filter_selected");
});

$('.filter_btn2').click(function () {


    $(".filter_btn2").removeClass("filter_selected");
    $(this).addClass("filter_selected");
});


$('.filter_reset_btn').click(function () {
    location.reload();

});

function filter() {
    alert(filcomp);
    func();
    $(".post").hide();
    $("div").filter(filcomp).show();
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to main div and show hide its child according to filter please see below code

```
<div class="row mainfilter">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none filter1 filter1_only">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                        <h4>filter1 only content</h4>


                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none  filter1 filter2 filter3">
                        <a href="">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                                <h4>filter1 and filter2 and filter 3</h4>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-left st_dis_none   filter2 filter3">
                        <a href="">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-padding">

                                <h4>filter2 and filter 3</h4>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
        $('#filter1').click(function () {


            $(".mainfilter").children().hide();
            $(".filter1").show();

        });
    });

    //
    $(function () {
        $('#filter2').click(function () {

            // $(".filter1_only:not(.filter2_only .filter2)").hide();
            // $(".filter3_only:not(.filter2_only .filter2)").hide();
            $(".mainfilter").children().hide();
            $(".filter2").show();

        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#filter3').click(function () {

            // $(".filter1_only:not(.filter3_only .filter3)").hide();
            // $(".filter2_only:not(.filter3_only .filter3)").hide();
            $(".mainfilter").children().hide();
            $(".filter3").show();

        });
    });
```

Comment: that is not the answer i need. like when filter 2 is selecte filter1_only stays..
Some way to do this with arrays?